# The text box background color doesn't disappear

Tags: vba, excel, powerpoint

```
Set shp = aslide.Shapes.AddShape(Type:=msoShapeRectangle, Left:=50, Top:=185, Width:=600, Height:=26.6)
    shp.Line.Visible = msoFalse
    shp.TextFrame.TextRange.Font.Color.RGB = RGB(10, 47, 93)
    shp.TextFrame.TextRange.Characters.Text = "HI"
    shp.TextFrame.TextRange.Paragraphs.ParagraphFormat.Alignment = ppAlignLeft
    shp.TextFrame2.VerticalAnchor = msoAnchorMiddle
    shp.TextFrame2.TextRange.Font.Size = 28
    shp.TextFrame2.TextRange.Font.Name = "Arial"
```

I have a default layout for my slides in a light blue color, but when I add this text box, i want the text color to be dark blue which it is, and I can see the text, but the background of the text box does not disappear even when I haven't used a fill function. How to solve this, it looks really terrible. Thanks in advance.

Comment: So the background the textbox is being placed on is light blue, the text in the text box is dark blue, and the background of the text box is white, or some other color making it stand out and look weird?

Comment: @Dportology yes i am thinking the same, but how do I get rid of it, as I haven't added any fill options in my code. Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this should do the trick:

```
shp.Fill.Transparency = 0
shp.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(0, 0, 0)
shp.Fill.BackColor.RGB = RGB(0, 0, 0)
```

Sets your back color and forecolor on the shape to black, just switch this color out to match your background color in RGB and you should be fine.

Alternatively, I just tested setting the transparency to full ie:

```
shp.Fill.Transparency = 1
```

and this works, as it just ignores whatever color was set by default.

Comment: shp.Fill.Transparency = 1, works totally good. Thanks man, I appreciate that.